# convert character column to numeric type by calculating its mean value

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have `age` column of character type. How do I replace all `age_char` with `corresponding_age_num` in column `age`

Thanks

```
library(tidyverse)

countries <- c("America", "Brazil", "Canada", "Denmark", "England", "France")
age <- c("70 to 75", "unknown", "75 to 80", "70 to 75", "80 and above", "75 to 80")

tbl <- tibble(countries, age)

age_char <- unique(tbl$age)

correponding_age_num <- (72.5, 50, 77.5, 85)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if we do the split at the 'to' to create two numeric columns, we can do the average

```
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)  
tbl %>%
   separate(age, into = c('age1', 'age2'), sep = '\\s+to\\s+|[^0-9]+',
       convert = TRUE, remove = FALSE) %>%
   transmute(countries, age, age_mean = case_when(str_detect(age, 
                'and above') ~  age1 + 5, TRUE ~ (age1 + age2)/2))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#  countries age          age_mean
#  <chr>     <chr>           <dbl>
#1 America   70 to 75         72.5
#2 Brazil    unknown          NA  
#3 Canada    75 to 80         77.5
#4 Denmark   70 to 75         72.5
#5 England   80 and above     85  
#6 France    75 to 80         77.5
```

if we need the `unique` values and its corresponding mean, then wrap with `distinct`

```
tbl %>%
   separate(age, into = c('age1', 'age2'), sep = '\\s+to\\s+|[^0-9]+',
       convert = TRUE, remove = FALSE) %>%
   transmute(countries, age, age_mean = case_when(str_detect(age, 
                'and above') ~  age1 + 5, TRUE ~ (age1 + age2)/2)) %>% 
   select(-countries) %>% 
   distinct(age, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you very akrun.

Comment: Sometime, age is written as "80 and above" or "not disclosed". I can check all uniques values using unique(tbl$age). Is there a way to create a separate array of desired values and somehow map to unique values. For example - unique values are c("70-75", "75-80", "unknown"). We create a array c(72.5, 77.5, 50) and use this to replace all character values

Comment: @SiD can you try the update.  I am not sure what all patterns you have in the original data

Comment: @SiD that would be great and please edit with all the patterns

Comment: I have edited the question, I can manually give value for each age class

Comment: @SiD how do you get `50` as average

Comment: good question, that is just a dummy value for now :)

Comment: @SiD Do. you expect `NA` for `unknown`

Comment: @SiD please check the expected output

Comment: I can get all unique char values using unique(tbl$age). I can manually create an array of corresponding age values. For ex - unique values are c("70-75", "75-80", "unknown"). I can create a array c(72.5, 77.5, 50). How do I replace all character values with these numeric values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229662/discussion-between-sid-and-akrun).

Answer (score 1):

```
    library(tidyverse)

countries <- c("America", "Brazil", "Canada", "Denmark", "England", "France")
age <- c("70 to 75", "75 to 80", "75 to 80", "70 to 75", "80 and above", "75 to 80")

tbl <- tibble(countries, age)

tbl <- tbl %>% 
mutate( num1 = str_extract(age,"^[0-9]{1,3}"),
    num2 = str_extract(age, "to [0-9]{1,3}" ),
    num2 = str_extract(num2, "[0-9]{1,3}"),
    num1 = num1 %>% as.numeric(),
    num2 = num2 %>% as.numeric())  

tbl$mean <-apply(tbl[,3:4], mean , MARGIN = 1)


tbl   


# A tibble: 6 x 5
  countries age           num1  num2  mean
  <chr>     <chr>        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 America   70 to 75        70    75  72.5
2 Brazil    75 to 80        75    80  77.5
3 Canada    75 to 80        75    80  77.5
4 Denmark   70 to 75        70    75  72.5
5 England   80 and above    80    NA  NA  
6 France    75 to 80        75    80  77.5
```